# jq test if any of several substrings is in a string

Tags: iteration, jq

Let's say I have a list of items like this:

```
[
  "abcdef",
  "defghi",
  "euskdh"
]
```

I want to write a filter that returns all of the items that contain an "a", "d", or "h". This is the best I could come up with:

```
. as $val | select(any(["a", "d", "h"]; inside($val)))
```

Is there any way to do it without using a variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your jq has regex support:

```
map(select(test("a|d|h")))
```

Or if you want a stream of values:

```
.[] | select(test("a|d|h"))
```

If your jq does not have regex support, then if it has any/2, the following will produce a stream of values:

```
.[] | select( any( index( "a", "d", "h"); . != null ) )
```

All else failing, the following will do the job but is inefficient:

```
 .[] | select( [index("a", "d", "h")] | any )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using **index**

```
  .[]
| if index("a") or index("d") or index("h") then . else empty end
```